# Removing whitespace from MySQL columns using Python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have an application connected to a MySQL database from Python.

I would like to remove all new lines, tab characters, and extra space from each entry in every table.

Can I do this, for example using `update` and `split`?

Here is my first step:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb as mdb



con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');

with con: 

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 1")
    rows_1 = cur.fetchall()
    print rows_1


    for row in rows_1:
        inString = rows_1;
    str = inString.replace("\n", "");
        print row
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the schema from mysql information_schema's COLUMNS table, with

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name" GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

Then get columns for each table by

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME="table_name" AND TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name"
```

Then select out the columns with data type you want to update, like char, varchar and text.

Then update the data.

Comment: I know how to update in mysql.. please check my question once